# What is the Kalman Filter in the basics of its aspects?

Tags: kalman-filter

My question is very broad. However I would like a complete description to the very last detail in a way that a foreign exchange student would understand. I want to try my best to master the way the Kalman Filter works. Please be as through as you possibly can, and more.

Comment: This question is being asked all the time. Check out the existing answers which contains very valuable links to tutorials/explanations/etc.

http://robotics.stackexchange.com/search?q=kalman

Answer (score 1):

Imagine watching a bird flying behind some trees.  You can observe the bird's speed and direction, and when it passes behind a tree you have an expectation of (approximately) where you will see it appear on the other side.  If the tree is wide, or there are several trees in a group, the bird will be hidden for longer -- and there will be a larger set of possibilities for where you might see the bird again.  A Kalman filter is a more formal version of this process.

Because this is a statistical technique, it works best when the possible variations in the path of the bird (or whatever you're filtering) follow a gaussian distribution -- in other words, are completely random.

Those are the very basic concepts, and I'm not sure how I'd explain the rest any better than something you'd find on Google.

Answer (score 0):

"Please be as through as you possibly can"

This is a book length subject.  To cover it completely would required hundreds of pages of text.

The best way to learn, and I'm just starting to learn is to start out very simple.  Make a filter where the state is just a 2D vector and the measurements look a LOT like the state.

Then you try a harder problem and so on.   I doubt you can learn by reading.  I can't.  I have to use the theory to learn it.  This is a very good and simple explanation, about as simple as in can get: [Kalman tutorial](http://greg.czerniak.info/guides/kalman1/)